# Create new app from Business account

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

I'm building an iOS app with Facebook integration.

I need to create an app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

But my client doesn't have a personal account on Facebook.

Then I created a business account and I'm trying to create an app with this account.

I succeeded yesterday, but now I can't assign administrator, can't post, etc...

How I can proceed ?

Comment: Surely questions about developer accounts are on topic for the official developer question and answer forum for Facebook? This question is about the kind of account you need if you are writing an app with the API, not about a Facebook account in general.

Comment: Voting to reopen; this question is only barely related to development, in that it refers to facebook's app settings interface, and not to the machanics of building an app - but this gets asked a LOT, and i think having a good question and answer here to direct repeat askers to is a good thing

Comment: @Igy Try to write your own canonical question and answer instead as described at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: gotcha, thanks! - i'll effectively be using the same answer i added here before we closed it, but that's probably fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account

Answer (score 7):

'Business' accounts can't manage apps - if you were able to create one as a business account this is a bug or loophole - only real verified user accounts should be able to create and manage apps.

Only real accounts should own and manage the account; if you need to share ownership you can do so either via making a Group an admin and adding the other admins to that group, or by adding the users directly via the API or the 'Roles' tab of the App settings

You can also specify a business account which will manage the ads for an app in the app settings - on the Advanced tab - but this is effectively the only supported connection between apps and business accounts - [image: screenshot here]

Comment: You seem to have posted a good answer to a good question, then  closed it as off-topic. It's a question about how to develop a Facebook app, and therefore about "software development in some way", therefore on topic. It's also a "practical, answerable question based on actual problems that were faced".

Comment: Based on your feedback i've asked and answered this again elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account