# Facebook app id get one

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Ok so ive been sitting here for 2 hours trying to figure out how to get a facebook app id. I have followed everyones links, and so forth and UGH! Everytime I go to developers page and app It brings me to my facebook, repeatively! It is quite annoying actually. I have verified my account with my cell phone. Yet I cannot seem to get it to go to the page where I add the display name, and url of my website. Please someone help me a little more

Comment: Are you logged in with your personal user or a "page" user?

Comment: follow this link https://developers.facebook.com/apps and moreover you need to be a valid Facebook user to create an app

Comment: ok so it can't be a "page" user?

Comment: Wow that is ridiculous! They should say that it needs to be personal. I tried this a month ago for a few days, thinking it had to be a business page. It made sense to me i guess. Well I figured everything out thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

To make a facebook APP id, you must have a personal account, and not a page. Do not be like me and try doing this with a "page".