# How do i get my App ID

Tags: facebook, app-id

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

How do I get an app ID whenever I try I get forwarded back to my adverts.

When I click on http://developers.facebook.com/ and apps it takes me back to my adverts!

Comment: Are you using your personal Facebook account?

Answer (score 8):

1. Login to Facebook
2. Go to Facebook Developers Application  page : https://developers.facebook.com/apps
3. Choose one app that you set up for a target before
4. Within the description, you will find APP ID.

Comment: That don't work it just takes be back to my comppaigns

Comment: @abdel - The OP stated in his question that he can not reach that URL.

Comment: @lix I'm using my business page

Comment: @user1691465 - I've answered many questions like this. you are going to have to use a personal Facebook account.  Page accounts can not open applications.

Comment: Well that's a pain. Thank you

Comment: try to go to the url after login to your personal Facebook account. it work for me:)