# Can't find the app dashboard for Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

I know it sounds kind of strange but I've been looking everywhere. I am registered as a facebook developer and am trying to follow this tutorial.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register

When I click the link that says "create a new app on Facebook" I get directed to my facebook page, and there is no sign of any app dashboard. I've tried several other links from other webpages, and the same thing happens. This includes the app button at the top of the facebook developers website.

Does someone know what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you like developer page? I clicked your link and still got application manager panel.

Comment: I just liked it, unfortunately it's still taking me to my facebook page.

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in with a regular user account and not a business account? if not, see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account

Comment: You mean for the _App Center_?

Comment: Igy. It seems like this was the issue, thanks. Strange that no where did it seem Facebook mentioned this requirement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igy stated that I had to use a regular account and not a business one.