# https://developers.facebook.com/apps takes me back to my Facebook Admin Panel

Tags: facebook, api

I want to get Facebook API for my site but when I to go https://developers.facebook.com/apps it doesn't work, instead it takes me back to my Facebook Admin Panel so I can't get the
API.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What d u mean by "get Facebook API"? Do u want to get authenticated to your website thru facebook?

Comment: I just want to get "Facebook API ID" and "Facebook App Secret" to add to an application on my site to enable users login with their facebook account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 0):

To get the Facebook API ID and Facebook App Secret, follow the following steps:

1. Got developers.facebook.com/apps and login with your account user id and password.
2. Click on Register as a developer button(green coloured) and follow and complete the verification process.
3. After verification process, if u login again and go to developer.facebook.com/apps, you will get the +Create New App button clicking on which and following you would be able to get the App ID and secret.

Let me know if you are having any problems with this.

Comment: thanks, i have registered, but the problem is that when i point my browser to developers.facebook.com/apps it takes me back to my Facebook Admin Panel. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Have you clickd on the green button "register as a developer" and followed the wizard?

Comment: Ok! just do me a favour.Kindly attach a screenshot of your Facebook Admin panel- the page where u are being redirected.

Comment: i can't see where to attach the screen or how do i send you private message instead.

Comment: Edit your question and see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46285/how-to-add-image-to-so