# Is there a limit on how many Facebook Apps can be created per Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, limit, app-id

I've created a new Facebook profile specifically for the purpose of managing Facebook Apps for our client websites. We are doing this because we work with many clients and have over 15,000 websites so we want to keep the FB account separate from our personal FB profiles and so that it can be shared by multiple support reps.

I wanted to ask does Facebook enforce any limit on how many App's 1 Facebook profile can create?

Is there an upper limit like 500, 5000, that is not documented or no limit at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Comment: Not a duplicate, my question is not about business accounts but the limit of Apps a Facebook profile can have.

Comment: Oh, i thought you said you were planning on adding the apps to a shared Facebook account, which would need to be a business account unless you want it auto-disabled - short answer to your question is 'no, but after about 500 apps the app management interface starts to become unusable'