# How to get FB login API_KEY and secret for business page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have created my ecommerce website's business page from my personal account. To enable FB login to my website, I need the API_KEY and SECRET. From the business page, I cannot find how to create it but can create one from my personal account.

How do I create the keys from my business page?

If I create it from my personal account, will that be the proper way to do it? (Somewhere, it sounds like similar to phishing -- how will FB associate my website to keys created from my personal account?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Comment: @Igy if you have found it as a duplicate, mention that with the link. Why mark -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Only users can create apps not businesses

You set the domains which an app can be used from in the settings page

And Facebook here explicitly mentions to use personal account for app development: https://www.facebook.com/help/117200265032897

Comment: are you saying that I can create the keys from my personal account and use it on my website?

Comment: Yes. Sign in with your personal account and you will see the options

Comment: regarding 'setting the domain in settings page', cannot someone else do the same for my website?

Comment: Sure. But they can not put the code on your website. So it would be pointless for them to do so