# How does a company develop and own a facebook application

Tags: facebook, ads, user-accounts, facebook-ads-api

Our company needs to automate creation and maintaining Facebook Ad campaigns. As Ads API is restricted to use only by applications, we dicided to develop one. Access to ability to develop was requested to facebook team, after what they congratulated us with abiltity to use Ads API and provided some information from help.

The problem is that we use a **business** account, in which an application *cannot be created*. So in what way our business account may assign developers, administrators and own an applicaton?
I searched over StackOverflow and googled it but found no usefull info. For example, I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account), which is, as I see by duplicates, very popular, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: How about asking facebooks support?

Comment: Great idea, but... how can I do it? at facebook [support page](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) I can see only developers' group and StackOverflow, where I posted my question directed firstly to Facebook team.

Comment: Well the question you mentioned already tells you that only personal accounts can create apps. And then there’s also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Answer (score 0):

here's the documentation on creating a Facebook Application: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/register-facebook-application

This is a firm requirement to have a regular Facebook account to create an application.