# Managing Facebook app created with a Business Account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-accounts

I have a Facebook Business Account, which I used to create 84 pages (for 84 countries). Years ago, everything worked perfectly. But today, I can't access the API anymore, which is deprecated for Business Accounts. The solution presented on [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account) doesn't work anymore: the app dashboard link now redirects back to the list of user administered pages.

I created a Personal Account and gave it Admin rights to all pages. It works, but Facebook blocks the new account constantly (as it was probably flagged for transferring the ownership of too many pages). The account is currently blocked because of this, and I can't unblock it due to errors in the Facebook platform.

Since it has become a burden to unblock the account so many times (around 20 times already), and every time it takes days for it to be unblocked, I would like to know if there is a solution to using the API with these pages that doesn't involve giving Admin right to a new personal account, or at least doing so without having my account flagged by Facebook.

Comment: That it was blocked due to transferring of pages is just a guess, I suppose? Is it a _real_ account, or did you create a fake one? If the latter, you mustn’t wonder if it gets blocked. You are only allowed to have one personal Facebook account, and it has to bear your real name.

Comment: @CBroe I created the account and use it only for this, but using my real personal data (had none prior to that). The pages were never blocked, but the account is. It was blocked just as I transferred some pages, so the problem is really this.